# Select By Location tools (intersect the source layer)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point-in-polygon, select-by-location, intersect

I want to find points are in the boundaries of polygons so I use Select By Location tools in a large area as country so I have many polygons (in shapefile) and the points (in shapefile) that is expanded in this large area I choose the item, 'Intersect the source layer feature'.

Is there any way to select points with considering larger boundary?

As you can see in image point B is in the yellow boundary and point A is not in yellow boundary so the result with Select By Location tools (Intersect the source layer) is point B but I need A and B because A is in the larger boundary as well (yellow boundary).  You know yellow boundaries are subsidence polygons and any points in this area must be selected. that means we ignore some areas that are in these larger yellow boundaries and are not yellow (maybe they are noises, in radar signal).

I am using ArcMap.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Setting**

[image]

**2. Minimum Bounding Geometry - Gemometry type - convex hull**
Or you can try [eliminate-polygon-part](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate-polygon-part.htm)

[image]
[image]

**3. Select by Location --> within**

[image]

If you have some parts outside it could help to use Multipart to single part [Multipart to singleplart](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/multipart-to-singlepart.htm)

If you have more features to process you can use batch process

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time spend for answering my question  and  your answer is exactly  correct and  that is what i want  Thank you very much